# AutoCompleteTextField and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, autocomplete, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to integrate Firebase and AutoCompleteTextField in Swift so that I have autocomplete in the textField. I'm having a problem trying to turn the dictionary into an array so that I can set it in `autoCompleteTextField.autoCompleteStrings`. This is the code I have for it.

```
func handleTextFieldInterfaces() {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Airport")
        ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    self.autoCompleteTextField.onTextChange = {[weak self] text in

            if !text.isEmpty {
            var fbosStuff = [String]()
                if let snaps = snapshot.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                for places in snaps {
                    print(places)
                    let names = places["code"] as? String
                    fbosStuff.append(names!)
                }
                 self!.autoCompleteTextField.autoCompleteStrings = fbosStuff

                }
            }

        }
    })
}
```

and the response from Firebase that I am trying to put into the textfield is.

```
Snap (Airport) {
"Long Beach" =     {
    FBOs =         {
        Atlantic =             {
            100LL = "7.0";
            freq = "120.1";
            fullname = "Atlantic, Long Beach, KLGB";
            "jet-A" = "5.5";
            "phone number" = "(800) 554-3591";
        };
        Signature =             {
            100ll = "7.0";
            email = "lgb@signatureflight.com";
            freq = "120.1";
            fullname = "Signature, Long Beach, KLGB";
            "jet-a" = "5.5";
            phonenumber = "(800) 554-3591";
        };
    };
    code = KLGB;
    fieldname = Daughtery;
    location = "Long Beach, California, USA";
};
"Santa Monica" =     {
    FBOs =         {
        "American Flyers" =             {
            100ll = "5.38";
            freq = "123.3";
            fullname = "American Flyers, Santa Monica, KSMO";
            phonenumber = "(310) 390-2099";
        };
        Atlantic =             {
            100ll = "7.79";
            freq = "122.95";
            fullname = "Atlantic, Santa Monica, KSMO";
            "jet-a" = "7.19";
            phonenumber = "(310) 396-6770";
        };
    };
    code = KSMO;
    fieldname = "Santa Monica Muni Airport";
    location = "Santa Monica, California, USA";
};
```

}

Comment: if you want get to value "code" you need to get deeper, you can see it is deep in your response, read about maping json. Try step by step go and check how to print just what you need

Comment: I'm trying to get the "Santa Monica" and the "Long Beach" into an array

Comment: so what do you see if you print this line print(places)

Comment: I get both printed at the same time. I need one after the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try :-

**Swift 2**

```
for places in snaps {

  print(places.0)  // Will give you the key
  let names = places["code"] as? String
  fbosStuff.append(names!)

 }
```

**Swift 3**

```
for places in snaps {

  print(places.key)  // Will give you the key
  let names = places["code"] as? String
  fbosStuff.append(names!)

 }
```

Comment: This gets me the 2 keys. But I need to get the keys into an array. They both print out together.

Comment: What do you mean print together?